# Construct a turing machine that accepts L = {ww : w belongs to {a,b}*}

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Construct a Turing machine that accepts $L = \{ww : w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$?

Comment: It will often be more expeditious to provide your own thoughts about solving a problem, or at least what makes such a Question interesting to you (or difficult), rather than asking Readers to respond without an indication of how far you got on this.  Such context helps avoid repeating material already known to you (such as definitions) or supplies useful information to future Readers who may not yet know those basic definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you write a machine that turns
$$ \ldots 0 0 0 x \alpha y 0 \beta 0 \gamma 0 0 0\ldots$$
(where $x,y\in \{a,b\}$ and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\{a,b\}^\star$) into 
$$ \ldots 0 0 0 \alpha 0 x\beta 0 y\gamma 0 0 0 \ldots$$
and the halts in a REJECT state if it sees
$$ \ldots 0 0 0 x 0 \ldots$$
?

Can you write a machine that turns
$$ \ldots \alpha x 0 y \beta\ldots$$
into 
$$ \ldots \alpha 0 \beta\ldots$$
if $x=y$ and halts with REJECT if $x\ne y$?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the input word is even. If so, construct a new word next to the input word by removing alternately the first and last letter from your input word and appending it to your new word. When you're done, check whether the new word is a palindrome.